# Why ı am getting error problem, when ı start npm from vs code terminal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make react project. Also I am using vs code. When ı want npm start from vs code's terminal, I get an error. Could you help me about how can ı solve this problem?

[image]

This is packade.json

```
   {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    
    },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show you `package.json` file? You should define your startup script there.

Comment: try `npm run-script start`

Comment: Please post code, logs and error messages as text, not as image.

Comment: The error message means that there is no `start` script in your `package.json`

Comment: Are you sure you have all needed file to run your application? index.js, package.js

Comment: Guys, I shared my pockaded.jsoon file

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly run `npm init` before and created a package.json, but with `npm start`, the terminal is looking for a script inside your package.json file called "start" (which is not yet there).

This is why you get the line `npm ERR! Missing script: "start"`.

If you want to declare a script with this name, you have to add it to the `scripts` object in your package.json first:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "some script you can define here"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```